# if statement not following its condition

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, break

I'm trying to have it so that if someone inputs anything besides 1, 2 or 3 they have to go back and input 1 2 or 3 however when I put 1, 2 or 3 then it still happens. If they input 1, 2 or 3 I would like it to go print the last line.

```
choice = input("\nPlease choose 1 for rock, 2 for paper, or 3 for scissors!   ")

if choice != "1" or "2" or "3":
    print("\nPlease select 1, 2 or 3 to coresspond to rock, paper or scissors\n")
    choice = input("\nPlease choose 1 for rock, 2 for paper, or 3 for scissors!   ")
else:
    print("The computer picks "+ x + "!")
```

The result I am getting is that I keep going back to the first line printed even if I have 1, 2 or 3. How do I skip that line and go to my last command if I already put 1, 2 or 3

Comment: Your if statement should be `if choice not in ['1','2','3']`.